# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and eval alternatives

Tags: jquery, json, eval, web-hosting

I have a function which is not working correctly on all hosting environments. The returned data is in JSON format. I think the problem is with eval(). Can I use any alternative for eval(). Please help me debug this or suggest any alternative approach.

**For three days, I am scrathing my head with this error (which appears only on few hostings but works fine on others)**

The data inLoad.php is as

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $text=$row['mesg'];
        $fro=$row['fro'];
        $tocomr=$row['tocom'];
        $last_msg_id_db=$row_m['maxid'];


        $response=array();

        //$response['msg']=$table;
        $response['msg']=$text;
        $response['last_msg_id_db']=$last_msg_id_db;
        $final_response[]=$response;

    }
          echo json_encode($final_response);
```

AND the data is returned as

```
    [{"msg":"hi<br>","last_msg_id_db":"173"}]
    main.php:96

    main.php:96
   [{"msg":"heloo<br>","last_msg_id_db":"174"}]
```

THe jquery function is as follows.

```
function chat_com_one(id, name) {
$('#chatcom').show('fast');
(function chatcom_load_one(id, name) {

    $.ajax({
        type:"Post",
        url:"load.php",
        data:{
            tocom:id,
            last_msg_id:last_msg_id
        },


        success:function(data) {

            var json = eval(data);
            $.each(json, function(i, row) {
                $("#commidwin").append(row['msg']);
                last_msg_id = row['last_msg_id_db'];
            });
            setTimeout(chatcom_load_one(id, name), 500);
        },
        error:function(XMLhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
            alert("error:" + textstatus + "(" + errorthrown + ")");
        }




    });
}(id, name));
}
```

The below error is given in Chrome's log

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier main.php:95
 $.ajax.success main.php:95
fire jquery.min.js:974
self.fireWith jquery.min.js:1082
done jquery.min.js:7788
callback
```

Comment: What does "eval" function receive as "data"? Provide the value of this variable.

Comment: @izogfif  i have updated my question and also added the data to be evaled.plz review

Comment: "data to be evaled" - need DATA, not the CODE generating this data. What symbols do you receive as the value of the variable "data" on the line "var json = eval(data);"?

Comment: @izogfif  this is the data.I also updated it in my question [{"msg":"hi<br>","last_msg_id_db":"173"}]
 main.php:96

 main.php:96
[{"msg":"heloo<br>","last_msg_id_db":"174"}]

Comment: What does "main.php:96" stand for? Why don't you wrap it inside some other object? Like {"main.php": 96}?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use eval. Simply set your `dataType` as `json` and jQuery will decode the JSON for you.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"load.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{
        tocom:id,
        last_msg_id:last_msg_id
    },
    success:function(data) {
        var json = data;
        $.each(json, function(i, row) {
            $("#commidwin").append(row['msg']);
            last_msg_id = row['last_msg_id_db'];
        });
        setTimeout(chatcom_load_one(id, name), 500);
    },
    error:function(XMLhttprequest, textstatus, errorthrown) {
        alert("error:" + textstatus + "(" + errorthrown + ")");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u ,but now error is alerted as "error:parseError(Syntax error:unexpected token<)"

Comment: I have updated my question and also added the data to be evaled.plz review